# iTunes byte range request conflict -- PHP download server solution?

Tags: podcasting

After submitting a podcast to iTunes, I got this error message: "Your episodes are hosted on a server which doesn't support byte-range requests. Enable byte-range requests and try your submission again."

[This post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-podpress-podpress-itunes-error-server-doesnt-support-byte-range-requests) from the Wordpress support forums and the other pages I've found refer to http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices as a solution, but I'm unclear on how to implement the provided code. Would it be added to a core file, saved as a separate file, or something else?

Any other potential solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.